# length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Tags: r

I'm trying to scrape data from smartgriddashboard.com using RSelenium.

More specifically I'm using this url tracked down via network part of dev tools which list all data for that day.

https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/data?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=28-Sep-2023+00%3A00&dateto=28-Sep-2023+23%3A59

I am trying to cycle through the days and months etc... to pull for all days and months over 2 years.

I'm getting the error

> length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

I've seen the answer at

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172507/error-in-parse-urlurl-lengthurl-1-is-not-true#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Likely%2C%20your%20problems%20arises%20because,than%20your%20loop%2C%20too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172507/error-in-parse-urlurl-lengthurl-1-is-not-true#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Likely%2C%20your%20problems%20arises%20because,than%20your%20loop%2C%20too)).

where GET call not properly integrated into loop but what I am wondering is can I fix this before going for an lapply, as I think the issue is in the inserting of values into the url?

```
# Initialise empty list and vector
tempds <- list()
months_years <- character(0)

years <- c('2022', '2023')
months <- c('Jan','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec')
last_day <- c('31','28','31','30','31','30','31','31','30','31','30','31')

# loop through years and months
for (year in years){
  i = 0
  base_url <- "https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/data?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=01-', month, '-', year,+00%3A00&dateto='"
  url_end <- paste0('%2023:59')
  for(month in months) {
    print(paste(month, year))
    url <- paste0(base_url, last_day, '-', month, '-', year, url_end)
    cat(url, "\n")
    print(url)
    if (year == '2023' && month == 'Sept'){
      print(paste(month, year, 'has been reached'))
      break 
    }
    
  # Send GET request and read CSV data
  response <- GET(url)
  if (http_status(response)$status_code == 200) {
    content <- content(response, "text")
    mds <- read_csv(content, na = "-")
    
    # Process the data
    mds$date <- as.POSIXct(mds$`DATE & TIME`, format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
    mds$Year <- as.integer(format(mds$date, "%Y"))
    mds$Month <- format(mds$date, "%b")
    mds$DayTime <- format(mds$date, "%d, %R")

    tempds[[length(tempds) + 1]] <- mds
    months_years <- c(months_years, paste(month, '-', year))
  
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It appears that when you're creating the URL itself, there are spaces and commas in it. I think that's simply a typo. See the line where you create the `base_url`.

Comment: It doesnt have to do with spaces and commas, which are appropriate in this context (ie, `paste0`) and not a typo. However, you aren't indexing anything in your loop(s): your url is `paste0(base_url, last_day, '-', month, '-', year, url_end)` which is the same as what you would get if you ran that outside your loop and returns length 12, hence the error

Comment: indexing properly in the loop as suggested solved the url problem but still getting the error. Updated loop code added above at end of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit more convenient to generate that list of dates, will also handle upcoming leap year. URL in the question points to JSON, for CSV there's another endpoint (`data` -> `csv`) and `read.csv` / `read_csv` can handle remote URLs, so unless http responses and status codes must be tracked, we can skip `httr`

```r
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# switch/set locale to get three-letter abbreviations for English
Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")
#> [1] "C"

# last-day-of-month 
# `1st day - 1` to get last day of previous month, hence the start from February
dates <- seq(from = ymd("2022-02-01"), to = ymd("2023-10-01"), by = "month") - 1
dates
#>  [1] "2022-01-31" "2022-02-28" "2022-03-31" "2022-04-30" "2022-05-31"
#>  [6] "2022-06-30" "2022-07-31" "2022-08-31" "2022-09-30" "2022-10-31"
#> [11] "2022-11-30" "2022-12-31" "2023-01-31" "2023-02-28" "2023-03-31"
#> [16] "2023-04-30" "2023-05-31" "2023-06-30" "2023-07-31" "2023-08-31"
#> [21] "2023-09-30"

# Month-YEAR
dates_from <- strftime(dates, "%b-%Y")
dates_from[1:5]
#>  [1] "Jan-2022" "Feb-2022" "Mar-2022" "Apr-2022" "May-2022" 

# day-Month-YEAR
dates_to <- strftime(dates, "%d-%b-%Y")
dates_to[1:5]
#>  [1] "31-Jan-2022" "28-Feb-2022" "31-Mar-2022" "30-Apr-2022" "31-May-2022"

# resulting vector lenght is defined by lengths of dates_from & dates_to
urls <- paste0("https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?",
               "area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=01-", dates_from, 
               "+00%3A00&dateto=", dates_to, "+23%3A59")
length(urls)
#> [1] 21
urls[1:3]
#> [1] "https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=01-Jan-2022+00%3A00&dateto=31-Jan-2022+23%3A59"
#> [2] "https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=01-Feb-2022+00%3A00&dateto=28-Feb-2022+23%3A59"
#> [3] "https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=01-Mar-2022+00%3A00&dateto=31-Mar-2022+23%3A59"

# purrr::map instead of lapply for the convenience of .progress
# read_csv (and read.csv) can read CSV from URL, 
# purrr::slowly(), to limit request rate
result_lst <- map(urls[1:3], 
                  slowly(read_csv), show_col_types = FALSE, 
                  .progress = TRUE)
#> ====================>---------- 67% | ETA: 2s 

result_lst[[1]] 
#> # A tibble: 2,976 x 3
#>    `DATE & TIME`        `ACTUAL GENERATION(MW)` REGION    
#>    <chr>                                  <dbl> <chr>     
#>  1 1 January 2022 00:00                    4394 All Island
#>  2 1 January 2022 00:15                    4457 All Island
#>  3 1 January 2022 00:30                    4408 All Island
#>  4 1 January 2022 00:45                    4414 All Island
#>  5 1 January 2022 01:00                    4459 All Island
#>  6 1 January 2022 01:15                    4648 All Island
#>  7 1 January 2022 01:30                    4508 All Island
#>  8 1 January 2022 01:45                    4428 All Island
#>  9 1 January 2022 02:00                    4442 All Island
#> 10 1 January 2022 02:15                    4442 All Island
#> # i 2,966 more rows
```

Bind frames in a list, parse date/time:

```r
result_lst |>
  list_rbind() |>
  mutate(date_time = dmy_hm(`DATE & TIME`), .before = 1, .keep = "unused")
#> # A tibble: 8,640 x 3
#>    date_time           `ACTUAL GENERATION(MW)` REGION    
#>    <dttm>                                <dbl> <chr>     
#>  1 2022-01-01 00:00:00                    4394 All Island
#>  2 2022-01-01 00:15:00                    4457 All Island
#>  3 2022-01-01 00:30:00                    4408 All Island
#>  4 2022-01-01 00:45:00                    4414 All Island
#>  5 2022-01-01 01:00:00                    4459 All Island
#>  6 2022-01-01 01:15:00                    4648 All Island
#>  7 2022-01-01 01:30:00                    4508 All Island
#>  8 2022-01-01 01:45:00                    4428 All Island
#>  9 2022-01-01 02:00:00                    4442 All Island
#> 10 2022-01-01 02:15:00                    4442 All Island
#> # i 8,630 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic, cuts through so much messiness directly getting the csvs this way.  I didn't know this coud be done, thank you!

Comment: Those data export options are sometimes fully javascript based (i.e. downloaded json is transformed to CSV by javascript)  but it's still worth to check those out. In this case it's plain CSV from the server -- if you download a CSV from dashboard and check the URL, you'll notice it comes from `https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/csv?area=demandActual&...`

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do nested `for` loops here if your goal is to find data for each month/year for the past two years. You can create a vector of URLs (here, `dts`) using `paste` and `expand.grid` and the use `lapply` with `http::GET`:

```
years <- c('2022', '2023')
months <- c('Jan','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec')
last_day <- c('31','28','31','30','31','30','31','31','30','31','30','31')

dts <- paste(last_day, apply(expand.grid(months, years), 1, paste, collapse = "-"), sep = "-")
end_date <- "28-Sept-2023"
base_url <- "https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/data?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom="

url <- paste0(base_url, dts, "+00%3A0&dateto=", end_date, "+23%3A59")

geturls <- lapply(url, httr::GET)

# > geturls
# [[1]]
# Response [https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/data?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=31-Jan-2022+00%3A0&dateto=28-Sep-2023+23%3A59]
# Date: 2023-09-29 15:49
# Status: 200
# Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
# Size: 136 B
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# Response [https://www.smartgriddashboard.com/DashboardService.svc/data?area=generationactual&region=ALL&datefrom=28-Feb-2022+00%3A0&dateto=28-Sep-2023+23%3A59]
# Date: 2023-09-29 15:50
# Status: 200
# Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
# Size: 136 B

# ....
```

This returns a list of length 24 (12 months x 2 years) each containing the results of the `httr::GET` function, and you can proceed performing your desired manipulations on those results using `lapply` -  ie, `content <- lapply(geturls, \(x) httr::content(x, "text"))`

Comment: This worked, I didn't know about expand.grid. Super useful ,thanks

Comment: Great! Glad it helped - `expand.grid` is sometimes super useful!